# HDD Storage with AHCI configuration is taking long time to respond to ATA commands

Tags: local-storage, storage, driver, sata, ahci

I have a laptop with M2 and Seagate HDD 500GB.
BIOS SATA/NVMe Operation is configured to AHCI/NVMe.
Windows 11 and IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers, Standard SATA AHCI Controller, version 10.0.22621.2506.

Application is trying to send ATA commands but the response for the same is very slow (at times more than 10 mins).
IOCTL IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT is send using WIN32API DeviceIoControl() API. The ATA register is configured to send ATA command, ATA_CMD_SMART, and sub command, SMART_READ_LOG.

Any idea why response from diver is taking so much time?

Regards,

Why ATA commands taking so long to respond?